# Adding Text after Post Title based on Category using IF Condition - But not for menu items

Tags: posts, title, labels

Some posts have a more "readable value" even though they are free to read. To highlight their increased reader value, I've managed to get together this piece of code.

"Problem" is, for some reason when navigation through the blog pages, the menu items gets the "Worth Reading" label as well - which is not the idea.

**My question is this;** am I doing this wrong or do I need to somehow include a "is_menu()" kind of conditional that I am not aware of?

```
add_filter('the_title', 'label_after_post_title', 10, 1);
function label_after_post_title($title){

  if (is_admin()) return $title;

    if (is_single() || is_category('worth-reading') || is_search()) return $title;

        $label = '';

        if (has_category('worth-reading')){

          $label = '<span class="worth-reading">Worth Reading</span>';
          $title = $title . '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $label;
        }
      return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `the_title()` filter is applied to the titles of posts and pages in menu items, so without any conditions any changes you make will also apply there.

It's worth breaking down your conditions to see why your change is still applying to menus:

- `is_single()` *Are we viewing a single post?* We may be, but nav menus are still typically displayed on single posts.
- `is_category()` *Are we viewing a category archive?` Again, we may be, but nav menus are still typically displayed on single posts.
- `is_search()` *Are we viewing search results?* Same again, this is still true for nav menu items.

So you need a condition to only apply a filter to post titles within [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/). The function you're looking for is [`in_the_loop()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_the_loop/).

I would go as far as to say that you don't want any of the other conditions you've used. Your goal is to display something next to the title of any posts in the loop that have the `worth-reading` category. As long as those conditions are met we don't really need to check the others:

```
function label_after_post_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    if ( in_the_loop() && has_category( 'worth-reading', $post_id ) ) {
        return $title . '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="worth-reading">Worth Reading</span>';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'label_after_post_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi Jacob,

I tested your code with a small change (due to nr of arguments given). I changed `add_filter( 'the_title', 'label_after_post_title', 10, 1 );` into `add_filter( 'the_title', 'label_after_post_title', 10, 2 );` and I added one more condition to the argument to make sure the label did not show on posts pages (`!is_singular('post')`) and it seems to work just fine.

Thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for your detailed answer. I learned something while fixing my problem. So, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may skip altering the title by checking if the post is a nav item using `is_nav_menu_item` Or you may just bail out by checking if the `get_post_type` != 'post'.